# Best way to queue threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, queue, runnable

I'm searching for a way to queue threads with Androïd.
I want to download pictures and for performances reason, I used a custom class which implements `Runnable` interface rather than an `AsyncTask`.

When I launch the activity I have almost 300 simultaneous threads executed... So I get `OutOfMemoryException`.

What is the best way to limit the number of simultaneous threads ?
Should I use [Android Queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html) or [BlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or something else ?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: why are you queuing threads? You should queue the runnable that the thread(s) should execute.

Comment: Or save time and just http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: This is a very good observation! I'll research about this.

Comment: I like how you spell Androïd. I think I'll adopt that...

Answer (score 2):

Use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with fixed thread pool size and keep posting / executing runnables.